# Entity Framework String Condition At List That Linked With ForeignKey

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

I am trying to develop a filterable topic list. There are 2 tables that linked with a foreign key. I should write a LINQ query that search topics by string filter sent by the client like "SpecId == 2 AND ValueBit == true". I used repository pattern in my service project and trying to do that but I couldn't implement filter as I want.

1. x.TopicSpecs.Where(condition) part doesn't work because the condition is a string. I tried to use DynamicQueryBuilder but Linq To Entities doesn't recognize it. x.TopicSpecs.Where(y=> y.SpecId == 2 && y.ValueBit == true) works, it should be coded dynamically.
2. Which one is correct, sending query to topicRepository or topicSpecRepository?

I spent my whole day on that, but couldn't solve this query. Could you help me, please?

**My Query**

```
Topics = await topicRepository.GetAllWithStringOrder(x => new TopicModel
            {
                CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate,
                Subtitle = x.Subtitle,
                Title = x.Title,
                UpdatedDate = x.UpdatedDate,
                Users = x.User.UserProfiles.Select(y => new UserProfileModel
                {
                    Nickname = y.Nickname
                }).ToList(),
                TopicId = x.TopicId,
                UserId = x.UserId,
                TopicCommentCount = x.TopicComments.Count,
                TopicSpecs = x.TopicSpecs.Where(y => y.Spec.ShowInTopic).Select(y => new TopicSpecModel
                {
                    ValueBit = y.ValueBit,
                    ValueDate = y.ValueDate,
                    ValueNumber = y.ValueNumber,
                    ValueString = y.ValueString,
                    Spec = new SpecModel
                    {
                        Name = y.Spec.Name,
                        SpecId = y.Spec.SpecId,
                        Color = y.Spec.Color
                    }
                }).ToList()
            }, x => x.IsActive && !x.IsDeleted && x.IsLatest && x.TopicSpecs.Where(condition).Count() > 0, model.ItemsPerPage.Value, model.PageNumber.Value, model.SortBy, !model.Reverse)
```

**GetAllWithStringOrder**

```
public virtual async Task<List<TReturn>> GetAllWithStringOrder<TReturn>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TReturn>> selectExp, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> whereExp, int itemsPerPage, int pageNumber, string orderBy, bool isDescending, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeExps)
    {
        var query = DbSet.Where(whereExp);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
        if (includeExps != null)
            query = includeExps.Aggregate(query, (current, exp) => current.Include(exp));
        query = query.OrderBy(orderBy, isDescending).Skip<TEntity>((pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage).Take<TEntity>(itemsPerPage);
        return await query.Select(selectExp).ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Topic Table**

```
public partial class Topic
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Topic()
    {
        this.TopicComments = new HashSet<TopicComment>();
        this.TopicContents = new HashSet<TopicContent>();
        this.TopicSpecs = new HashSet<TopicSpec>();
    }

    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsLatest { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TopicComment> TopicComments { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TopicContent> TopicContents { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TopicSpec> TopicSpecs { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**TopicSpec Table**

```
public partial class TopicSpec
{
    public int TopicSpecId { get; set; }
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public int SpecId { get; set; }
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> ValueBit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTimeOffset> ValueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ValueNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual Spec Spec { get; set; }
    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
}
```

**Spec Table**

```
public partial class Spec
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Spec()
    {
        this.TopicSpecs = new HashSet<TopicSpec>();
    }

    public int SpecId { get; set; }
    public int SpecTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool ShowInTopic { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public virtual SpecType SpecType { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<TopicSpec> TopicSpecs { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a Model class somewhere that this query is pulling properties from to run as indicated in the last line of that query:

```cs
.....  model.ItemsPerPage.Value, model.PageNumber.Value, ....
```

It might be helpful if that class was posted as well, though this is already quite a bit of code to sift through.

That said, the simplest solution to question #1 is probably to add some properties to that `model` class, and use those in the `Where` clause.

```cs
... x.TopicSpecs.Where(y=> y.SpecId == model.SpecIdValue && y.ValueBit == model.ValueBitFlag)....
```

In this example, the new model properties are `model.SpecIdValue` as an `int` and `model.ValueBitFlag` as a `bool`.

I assume you have that call to `Topics = await topicRepository.GetAllWithStringOrder...` inside of another method you are calling, so you can set the model properties I mentioned above and call that method again to get an updated response.

For question #2, if you are looking for a list of type `Topic` as the return from the query, you should use the topicRepository.

Comment: TopicSpecs' count is unknown by service so I can't make it like your solution.